# Getting an error as android.view.InflateException in the following code

Tags: android

I am creating an app which takes some data from user and send it to a number through sms.
But i get a runtime exception as Error Inflating Class .
Please try to figure out what i m doing wrong.
Thank you

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button submit;
EditText dst;
EditText name;
EditText roll;
EditText txt;
String phoneNumber="525252";
GPSTracker gps;
double lat,lon;
String message;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        dst = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        roll = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

        // Check if GPS enabled
        if(gps.canGetLocation()) {

            lat = gps.getLatitude();
            lon = gps.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + lat + "\nLong: " + lon, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
        else {
            // Can't get location.
            // GPS or network is not enabled.
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings.
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }

        submit.setOnClickListener(this);
}
            public void onClick(View v)

            {

                String dmd = dst.getText().toString();
                String nm = name.getText().toString();
                String md = roll.getText().toString();
                String msg = txt.getText().toString();
                String latt = Double.toString(lat);
                String lngg = Double.toString(lon);

                if (dmd.length()>0 && msg.length()>0 && nm.length()>0 && md.length()>0)
                {
                    message = "VISIT."+dmd+"."+nm+"."+md+"."+msg+"."+latt +"."+lngg;
                    sendSMS(phoneNumber,message);
                }
                else

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Please fill all the entries.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }


//---sends a SMS message to another device---

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)

{

    /*

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,

            new Intent(this, test.class), 0);

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);

    */

    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(SENT), 0);  
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);


    //---when the SMS has been sent---

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break; 
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));    
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);

}
}
```

This is my main activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_icon_vertical_padding"
tools:context="com.mts.visit.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
    android:text="DST                :" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Name   :" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
    android:text="Roll     :" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="phone" />



<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Message:" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:ems="13"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/dialog_fixed_height_major" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:text="Submit" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is activity_main.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

I included these permissions to manifest.

```
06-20 15:29:37.630: W/dalvikvm(1371): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3addba8)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371): Process: com.mts.visit, PID: 1371
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mts.visit/com.mts.visit.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #74: Error inflating class <unknown>
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #74: Error inflating class <unknown>
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at com.mts.visit.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     ... 11 more
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     ... 24 more
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x6
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:464)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3784)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:623)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:60)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:56)
06-20 15:29:37.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     ... 27 more
```

I think the error is in inflating view but i don't know how to resolve it
Please help me as i am new to it.

Comment: Make sure that values for: @dimen/dialog_fixed_height_major and @dimen/activity_horizontal_margin are presented in res/values folder

Comment: Yes they are


`<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>`




`<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>`

Comment: Are you sure, that values.xml (with above dimensions) is situated in res/values folder (not in res/values-es f.e. folder)?

Comment: Yes they are present in res/values/dimens.xml file

Comment: You haven't mentioned @dimen/dialog_fixed_height_major, that is used by your EditText

Comment: Thank you so much
I removed that value and it worked for me. :)

Comment: Great. I've added answer. Could you mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide value for @dimen/dialog_fixed_height_major to fix this issue.